# java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In PhoneGap V 3.3 application i use this function to download a file to the device
i added the File and File-transfer plugins and did all the configuration

```
downloadAgendaPage = function () {
var uri = encodeURI("http://*****/data/***.ics");
window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
            "dummy.pdf", { create: true, exclusive: false },
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.pdf", "");
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    fileEntry.remove();

                    fileTransfer.download(
                            uri,
                            sPath + 'Agenda.ics',
                            function (theFile) {
                                console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                                //showLink(theFile.toURI());
                                alertify.alert("Agenda file " + "Agenda.ics" + " downloaded to your root folder");
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                                console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                            }
                    );
                },
            fail);
    },
    fail);}
```

I'm debuging the application on nexus 7 running Android 4.4.2, and i got this error message

```
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031): java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getFile(FileUtils.java:684)
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$5(FileUtils.java:679)
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$16.run(FileUtils.java:349)
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$24.run(FileUtils.java:473)
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-18 12:04:32.514: W/System.err(21031):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this strange error is that i was manually updating the cordova-plugins.js file and manually adding the plugins js files, because they were n't added automatically.
Why they weren't added automatically? because i was doing it wrong ..

The Answer is don't build then add the plugins, instead add the plugin then build then replace www files with yours.

Comment: Same problem here, found problems in my manually updated cordova-plugins.js file.  Correcting that file solved the problem.